# String match for same text in different format

Tags: php

I have two mysql tables `trade` and `current`.  Both these tables have the same products but their names/attributes aren't in the identical format.

I'm trying to do a string match.  For example;

Trade Table

```
 $trade_name = "LIGUSTRUM JONANDRUM 3 Balls + 3 Stems";
    $trade_attribute = "Total H. 140/ 160";
```

Current Table

```
$our_name = "Ligustrum Jonandrum (3 Balls / Pom Poms)";
$our_attribute = "Height (cm):  140 - 160 (cm)";
```

I could easily do str_replace for this individually but i have over 1000 rows and the formats aren't consistent. I need a function to match the trade name/attribute to their counterparts in the `current` table.  As i'll be extracting the trade prices and matching them to the prices in the `current` table.

How do i solve this?

Comment: I don't think this can be answered in a reasonable way, because the transition from one format to another is not trivial and probably unique for each name and attribute. As you state yourself, *"the formats aren't consistent"*. But you need at least some kind of consistency to express it programatically (except you have invented an artificial intelligence or something). We only can tell you some ways to do it for this specific example, but I guess that's not quite the point of your question.

Comment: Only inconsistency is the format.. the name and attributes are always in both. whether in capitals or not, or brackets etc.

Comment: So is the text always the same? Sorry, I don't quite get it - maybe you could show a few more datasets.

Comment: The name and attributes are always the same but the only thing different is the brackets, dashes, slashes.  Would strpos be a good solution?

Comment: Short answer: I don't know. Please show a few more examples of what you're working with. Long answer: No, I don't think it would be a good solution. What would you check for? You need to define some abstract rules, e.g. "the first to words of the name can explicitly identify the product", but do names always start with 2 words? And do attributes always have 2 numbers in them which always represent heights of the stems? Does the order matter? Is height the only attribute? As I said, it's really hard to help if we don't know what you're working with and without knowing the abstract rules.

Answer (score 0):

strings inconsistency is truth. So the similarity is not definite. You can only produce a statistical algorithm to produce the maximum accuracy  to the similarity results and risk the max accepting rate. Sth like that:

```
<?php   
function replace($string){
return strtolower(str_replace(str_split('\\/:*+/()-."<>|'),'',$string));
}

 $trade_name = "LIGUSTRUM JONANDRUM 3 Balls + 3 Stems";
 $trade_attribute = "Total H. 140/ 160";

$our_name = "Ligustrum Jonandrum (3 Balls / Pom Poms)";
$our_attribute = "Height (cm):  140 - 160 (cm)";

 $trade_sum=replace($trade_name).replace($trade_attribute);

  $our_name_sum=replace($our_name).replace($our_attribute);

$first_array = explode(' ', $trade_sum);
$second_array = explode(' ', $our_name_sum);

$array_differences= array_diff($first_array, $second_array);
$different_entries = count($array_differences);

$total_entries = count($first_array);
 $similarity = 100-( $different_entries / $total_entries ) * 100;
echo $similarity.'%';

//in your case we get 80% similarity
```